# Nuxt3 generate dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, router

Inside my nuxt.config.ts I can generate multiple routes with this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  generate: {
    routes: ['/products/1', '/products/2']
  },
})
```

When I run `nuxt generate` this will create inside my dist folder the product folder with two folders (product 1 and product 2, which contains the HTML).

But this route products will be GET on an API endpoint, so I want to generate it inside my page directly. On nuxt 2 we have to do this https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#routes.

```
generate: {
    routes: ['/products/1', '/products/2']
  }
```

When I do this on nuxt3 my products pages is not generated, I don't know if the property generated is still available and how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use nitro, it's a plugins add inside nuxtJs 3.

With this we can add a api call async and create the route we want:

```
import axios from 'axios'

async function getProductsRoutes() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://mydata/api/products/list.json')
  return data.map(product => `/products/${product.id}`)
}

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  hooks: {
    async 'nitro:config'(nitroConfig) {
      if (nitroConfig.dev) return

      let slugs = await getProductsRoutes();
      nitroConfig.prerender.routes.push(...slugs);
      return
    },
  },
})
```

I don't find a way to achieve this directly inside the page, and at this time i'm not be able to pass some payload.